# How to auto close an alert after few seconds with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, alert, auto-close

I have developed a Python/Flask application and ran into an issue implementing a Bootstrap alert where the idea is to:

- dismissible via a close button.
- fade out and close after 2s if no action is taken.

### Code

```
<div class="container">
        {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}   
        <script>       
          function close_alert()
          {
            document.getElementById("my_alert").close()
          }
          setTimeout("close_alert()", 2000)
        </script>
        <div id="my_alert" class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          <strong>{{message}}</strong>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I'm fairly new to Bootstrap and I would appreciate any support!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `.hide()` rather than `.close()` in close_alert function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap methods to achieve this. [Take a look here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) at the bottom of the page for more info.

### Logic

When the button is clicked jQuery removes the class `d-none` of the alert element which makes it visible. And then by using `setTimeout()` JS will wait 2000ms before closing the alert with `alert()` bootstrap 4 method.

It will work for only one click.

**Note**: using *Bootstrap 4 methods* requires to work with jQuery.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){

  $('#alert').removeClass('d-none');
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.alert').alert('close');
  }, 2000);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-primary m-3 d-none" role="alert">
  This is a primary alert—check it out!
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary m-3" id="btn">
  show alert and close it in 2 seconds
</button>
```

### With plain JavaScript

This code will show the alert every time the user clicks the button. In case you don't want that, you could use a Boolean or a session storage variable combined with a conditional statement to make it work only once.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
      alert = document.getElementById('alert');
      
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  alert.classList.remove('d-none');
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert.classList.add('d-none');
  }, 2000)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-primary m-3 d-none" role="alert">
  This is a primary alert—check it out!
</div>

<button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary m-3">
  show alert and close it in 2 seconds
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gass! I guess there was something wrong with my Bootloader as I was trying to do this using the v5, now that I switched to v4.6 and used your suggestion, everything is working good. I made some small changes to the code to suit my needs:

Comment: HTML -> "<div id="alert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{message}}</div>"

Comment: JS -> "setTimeout(function(){$('.alert').alert('close')}, 2000)"

Comment: @ftani Yeap, that's what you need. I had to add more code to make it work here. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a "toast"-- this is a UI component intended for your use case: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/

[image]
From Bootstrap docs:

```html
<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
    <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small class="text-muted">11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Hello, world! This is a toast message.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Matt Morgan! For the project I have in mind, an Alert is more suitable than a Toast.